# Verify my notify_url code for PayPal

Tags: php, paypal, checkout

**notify_url.php**

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
$sql = "UPDATE tablename 
        SET credit = credit + {$_POST['amount']} 
        WHERE username = '123456789'";
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
?>
```

**form html**

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
          <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="6RNT8A4HBBJRE">
          <input type="image" 
            src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" 
            border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
          <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" 
            width="1" height="1">
            <input name="amount" value=10.95 type="hidden"> <<< not sure if this line should be here
            <input name="notify_url" value="notify_url.php" type="hidden">
    </form>
```

The above code is what I have in my notify_url.php file. My database is not being updated :(. My connection file is ok. And when I put a number instead of the POST variable it works fine. Which only means that my POST variable could be wrong or the script is not being called at all!

**Edit:**
The second code is the form that was generated from PayPal website (the Buy button).

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

You have `value=10.95`, wrap that in quotes `value="10.95"` - It's not a big deal, but good practice.

also `if(isset($_POST['amount'])){...}` or `if(!empty($_POST['amount'])){...}`

while making sure your column is `DECIMAL` with length/values like `10,2` for example, in order to be able to accept decimals such as 10.95

Consult:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html

The way I tested this was using:

```
$amount = $_POST['amount'];

$sql = "UPDATE tablename 
        SET credit = credit + $amount 
        WHERE username = '123456789'";
```

Or you can try using concatenates:

```
SET credit = credit + '".$amount."'
```

Also, your post action should be `action="notify_url.php"` rather than what you're using now.

---

Original answer before you posted your HTML form:

I have a suspicion that either your form element doesn't have a name attribute and/or a value, as well as not using a POST method.

If your form does not have a defined method being POST since you are using `$_POST['amount']`, it will default to a GET method, in turn failing silently.

Since you haven't posted your HTML form, you can base yourself on any of the following:

If using a hidden type with a preset value: (in this case, I used 1000).

```
<form method="post" action="your_handler.php">

<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1000">
<input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

If from user input:

```
<form method="post" action="your_handler.php">

<input type="text" name="amount">
<input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

You can also check if the form's element is set/empty by using:

`if(isset($_POST['amount'])){...}` or `if(!empty($_POST['amount'])){...}`

- Also make sure your column is an `int` rather than `varchar`, which can also be a or one of the reasons why your code may be failing.

---

I need to note that your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

as well as `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`.

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

- If that still doesn't work, post your HTML form and DB schema in order to be absolutely certain.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to rewrite the code as follow:

```
$sql = "UPDATE tablename SET credit = credit + ". $_POST['amount'] ." WHERE username = '123456789'";
```

Anyway I discourage that approach (pass the POST straight to the query) because vulnerable for mysql injection.

And try to change

```
    <input name="notify_url" value="notify_url.php" type="hidden">
```

in

```
    <input name="notify_url" value="http://www.domain.com/notify_url.php" type="hidden">
```

Comment: The direct query is just for testing phase. I'm so frustrated that it doesn't work! BTW, that change in syntax doesn't work.

Comment: did you receive from the POST the correct value?
what you get from var_dump($_POST['amount'])

Comment: I don't know what I receive. Apparently the notify_url.php file is never loaded. It just gets the post variables. Otherwise I would have print_r($_POST) to see the variables.

Comment: Sorry nik. Still no luck. I am trying to get someone to pay for airtime. https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/digitalgoods_ec/php?interactive=ON&env=sandbox <-- Is this link a good way to do it? Although a lot of it are not clear to me yet, I can surely try.